# Сортировка html таблицы, если в столбце разные типы данных, с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, сортировка, table, sortable

У меня возник вот такой вопрос: я столкнулся с тем, что нужно было сделать сортировку таблицы, всё бы хорошо, но в одном столбце были совсем разные значения, например: время, число строка, строка-тире-цифры, и тп. Я использовал [этот](https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/#symbolsbeforesorting) скрипт, и он довольно хорош, только вот именно этот столбец в таблице он сортирует криво (ниже скрин приложу), я понимаю что стрипт пытается отсортировать столбец, приводя значения к одному типу, но видимо ему это не по силам (а может это я не правильно понимаю). Так вот, подскажите, можно ли как-то адекватно отсортировать такой столбец в таблице? Приветствуются любые скрипты, алгоритмы на JS.

Столбец без сортировки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По возрастанию\спаданию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

входные данные как в 1 скрине выше, а выходные должны быть: Все строки по алфавиту, а потом все числа: Alala Aala > ENG Mob > ... > RGH-1243 > 0 > 50 или наоборот

Comment: А какой результат вы бы хотели увидеть? Как должы сортироваться такие данные? Что значит "*адекватно*"?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko, адекватно это не в разброс,  а как-то структурировано - числа к числам, слова к словам, и тп.

Comment: Приведите пример входных данных и то, как они должны выглядеть после сортировки.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, входнык данные как в 1 скрине выше, а выходные: Все строки по алфавиту, а потом все числа:
Alala Aala > ENG Mob > ... > RGH-1243 > 0 > 50

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте эту информацию в вопрос - она важна для решения вашей проблемы. Под вопросом есть кнопка "Править". Желательно данные должны быть не в виде картинки)